# Option Recompile equivalent in Postgres

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

Is there an equivalent command or configuration in Postgres that is similar to OPTION(RECOMPILE) in SQL Server ?

```
SELECT t1.c1, t1.c2 from table t1 where c1=5 and c3=9 OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

OPTION RECOMPILE in SQL Server forces the SQL Server engine to recompile the query and ignore reading data from any database cache.
I would like to shift some of my functionalities to Postgres database from SQL Server database, and therefore need an equivalent query or command for OPTION RECOMPILE.

Comment: Postgres doesn't use a plan cache the way SQL Server does. So I'd say just remove that part.

Comment: I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name. Keep in mind this query hint and others are not only proprietary to SQL Server, they are non-functional in the sense they do not affect query results.